# Spinner by arrayadapter acts "weird"

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner. Which i have overridden the custom dropdown getview.
I'm working in android 2.2

Problem is that the selected value gets replaced by the "default"(empty field) inserted value when reopening the selector: images to explain below, and the overridden code below them:

[image: Initial activity]

Now pressing the spinner:

[image: selection]

Now pressing robs, and then pressing spinner again

[image: Missing robs]

Dropdown overridden method:

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.fav_spinner_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.indentationField = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.indent);
            holder.nameField = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.levelCount = mList.get(position).getTier() != -1 ? mList
                    .get(position).getTier() : 0;
            holder.nameField.setText(mList.get(position).getDisplayName());
            if (holder.levelCount == 0) {
                holder.indentationField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.indentationField.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(params.leftMargin+((params.leftMargin+15)*holder.levelCount), params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin);
                holder.indentationField.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the `ViewHolder` pattern properly. Since `getDropDownView()` can be called for **any** item index and can be passed **any** recycled `View`, you need to properly reset all the dynamic data **every time**. Like this:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.fav_spinner_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.indentationField = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.indent);
        holder.nameField = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // The rest of this is dynamic data, based on the item position
    holder.levelCount = mList.get(position).getTier() != -1 ? mList
                .get(position).getTier() : 0;
    holder.nameField.setText(mList.get(position).getDisplayName());
    if (holder.levelCount == 0) {
        holder.indentationField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.indentationField.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(params.leftMargin+((params.leftMargin+15)*holder.levelCount), params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin);
        holder.indentationField.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.indentationField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Also notice the line I added to reset the visibility of `indentationField` to `VISIBLE` because you might be recycling a `View` where the visibility was previously set to `GONE`

Comment: Thanks for the clearification, Though it still does it, now not on "robs" but on the others

Comment: I just noticed that you are getting the `LayoutParams` from `indentationField`, modifying them and then setting them again. This isn't going to work correctly either, as you may not be getting the original `LayoutParams`, you may be getting an already modified version. You need to look at how you are doing this all again.

Comment: Okay, so no viewholder pattern for me :)